# Как настроить nginx для отправки запросов сразу на 2 адреса

Tags: nginx, proxy

У нас nginx работает как прокси сервер для онлайн хранилища файлов. Как можно настроить, что бы при скачивании файла (или при прохождении любого трафика через этот прокси), nginx передавал файл как пользователю, который его запрашивает, так и другому серверу (у нас там антивирус)? Тоесть сразу в 2 места.

Comment: Нужно сначала проверить антивирусом а потом отдавать пользователю если все ОК? Или просто вторым запросом слать в антивирь и сразу отдавать пользователю?

Comment: Просто слать на антивирус и паралельно отдавать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, Nginx такое не умеет. Но есть варианты

## Первый вариант: X-Accel-Redirect

`X-Accel-Redirect` используется для контролируемых скачиваний.
Как должно работать:

### 1. Пишем скрипт на любом языке

`down.php`:

```php
<?php
// Публичная ссылка на файл
$path = $_GET["path"];

// Тут тем или иным способом отправляем запрос или ссылку на файл в антивирус.
// Если эта операция долгая, то лучшее решение - в этом месте пишем в очередь,
// а отдельный воркер кидает из очереди в антивирус

// Это-заголовок для Nginx, откуда брать файл
header("X-Accel-Redirect: /files/" . $path);
```

### 2. Настраиваем Nginx

Доработайте конфиг под свои особенности и защитите `/files` от прямого доступа из браузера.

```
http {
   ....
   server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  your-domain.com;
       location / {
           rewrite ^/download/(.*) /down.php?path=$1 last;
           proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
           proxy_redirect     off;
           proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
           proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           client_max_body_size       10m;
           client_body_buffer_size    128k;
           proxy_connect_timeout      90;
           proxy_send_timeout         90;
           proxy_read_timeout         90;
           proxy_buffer_size          4k;
           proxy_buffers              4 32k;
           proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
           proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
       }
       location /files {
           root /var/www;
           internal;
       }
   }
}
```

Получается такой путь:

1. Запрашивается файл `/download/file.zip`, Nginx переписывает адрес и кидает в скрипт `/down.php?path=file.zip`.
2. Скрипт отправляет файл в антивирус (реализацию напишите сами)
3. Скрипт отдает Nginx заголовок `X-Accel-Redirect: /files/file.zip` и Nginx уже отправляет файл в браузер.

По сути, файл на проверку отправляет написанный скрипт. Если отправка - медленный процесс, используйте очереди.

Ссылки:

- [Официальная документация (en)](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/)
- [Статья на Opennet (ru)](https://www.opennet.ru/base/net/nginx_x_accel.txt.html)

## Второй вариант: auth_request

По сути похож на первый вариант.

### 1. Пишем скрипт на любом языке

В скрипте отправляем файл на проверку, в конце отдаем 2xx код.

### 2. Настраиваем Nginx

Поправьте пути и порты под свои реалии. [Документация](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html).

```
server {
  listen        80;
  server_name   your-domain.com;
 
  # сюда поступает запрос на скачивание
  location /download/ {
       # если аутентификации нет, дальше запросы не пойдут
       auth_request /auth;
       # проксируем на даунлоад-сервер с файлами
       proxy_pass  http://download-server;
  }
 
  # тут проводим проверку
  location = /auth {
       internal;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
       proxy_pass_request_body off;
       proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
  }
 
}
```

Путь такой:

1. Запрашивается файл `/download/file.zip`, Nginx идет на внутренний адрес `/auth`, который проксируется на `http://127.0.0.1:8080`, где находится скрипт
2. Скрипт отправляет файл в антивирус (реализацию напишите сами)
3. Скрипт отдает Nginx любой код из 2xx, Nginx воспринимает это как успешную авторизацию и отдает в браузер файл из `http://download-server`

## Третий вариант: Lua

Есть проект [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/) который позволяет писать программы на Lua прямо в конфигах Nginx. Обычный Nginx также позволяет это делать, но нужно будет в него добавить модуль Lua.

А способ похож на предыдущие два: получаем запрос, ставим в очередь проверки, а клиенту отдаем файл.

Самый интересный на мой взгляд способ, но требует изучения Lua и OpenResty.

## Четвертый способ: через логи

В location, с которого скачиваются файлы, пишите `access_log` в отдельный файл. А отдельный скрипт читает этот файл и отправляет на проверку. Может быть, даже это будет не файл, а сокет, тогда не придется следить за файлом, а сразу вычитывать из сокета, но я не уверен, что Nginx может писать в сокеты. Попробуйте.

Comment: псс... [mirror](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html) и недокументированный post_action (например в вопросе https://serverfault.com/questions/535429/nginx-post-action-proxy-pass-track-downloading-file что-то похожее на этот кейс)

Comment: @nörbörnën спасибо, не знал, надеюсь ТС дочитает до коммента

Comment: и ещё в [njs](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/njs/reference.html) есть возможность и X-Accel-Redirect выставить, и сделать сабреквест оторванный от запроса. но я не пробовал, так что нуждается в изучении